# Libgdx - Texture packer n^2

Tags: android, libgdx

If I create a texture atlas 2048x2048, must I also make each and every texture imported into the atlas a square of 2 dimension.

Because I'm wasting a lot of space if I do that.

But my guess also is that I have to, because the MipMap filter scales it down diagonally... So if I make a rectangle, it wouldn't know how to scale it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you don't need to use n^2 images in libGDX. You can just put in any sized image in the atlas and libGDX will handle it correctly. 
I never had any problems with scaling rectangular images, just using the libGDX code..

I hope this answers your question.